# Проблема подключения к MariaDB

Tags: php, mysql, https, mariadb

Добрый день. Есть проблема подключения к БД `MariaDB` на хостинге. В администрации хостинга говорят что проблема у меня в  коде. Запросы идут через `HTTPS` протокол.Вот пример кода  подключения

```
<?php
         $dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
         $dbuser = 'user';
         $dbpass = 'password';
         $db='db';

         $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db,TRUE, MYSQL_CLIENT_SSL);

         if(! $conn ) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
         }

         echo 'Connected successfully';
         mysql_close($conn);

   ?>
```

Можете подсказать где моя ошибка в подключении если оно такое и есть .Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А вы уверенны что в  $dbhost надо указать порт ? пробовали просто localhost? логин и пароль корректны ?

Comment: Да все корректно только не подключается.

Comment: phpmyadin используется порт 3036  для подключения

Answer (score 1):

Для давно удалённого [`mysql_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) - порт указывается именно неразрывно с хостом. Но у `mysql_connect` нет параметра для имени базы. Для выбора базы предназначена функция `mysql_select_db`, которую надо вызывать после соединения. Поэтому вы получаете закономерную ошибку от функции, передавая ей неверные параметры.

[`mysqli_connect`](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.construct.php) же напротив имеет отдельный параметр для номера порта и имени базы подключения. Поэтому вы пытаетесь подключиться вообще не к тому серверу. Корректно будет

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbport = 3036;
mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db, $dbport);
```

Comment: `[04-Apr-2018 10:35:58 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect() expects parameter 5 to be long, string given in /home/xxxx/public_html/test1/db.php on line 8
[04-Apr-2018 10:35:58 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /home/xxxxx/public_html/test1/db.php on line 11`

Comment: Я думаю что проблема в хостинге.

Comment: Проблема в вашем коде. Посмотрите что именно вы пытаетесь передать пятым параметром. А должно быть число. О чём однозначно говорит ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Во первых, не используйте `mysql_connect()`, это устаревшая функция, используйте mysqli or pdo
Во вторых. Если запросы идут через HTTPS то это не имеет отношения к базе данных.
В третьих, проверьте на каком порту крутится база данных, обычно дефолтный порт - 3306.
Ну и было бы неплохо увидеть какую ошибку вы получаете

Comment: `[04-Apr-2018 07:57:56 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysql_connect() expects at most 5 parameters, 6 given in /home/XXXX/public_html/test1/db.php on line 9`

Comment: При каждом обновлении страницы появляется такой код

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: ` [04-Apr-2018 08:46:41 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1130): Host 'xx.xx.xx.xx' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server in /home/xxxx/public_html/test1/db.php on line 7`

Comment: появляется такая ошибка

Comment: значит вашему хосту не разрешено подключится к серверу mysql

Comment: Это как  отключено у них.?